# EF Core relationship without foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How to setup a navigation property without declaring a foreign key?

I have two tables (`segment` and `category`), they can join using 2 columns (origin/destination) but they don't meet the foreign key constraint because they can have value that doesn't exist in the other table (so its not about null or not null)

**Segment**

```
Id   Date       OriginId  DestinationId
---------------------------------------
1    2020-01-10    1        2
2    2020-01-18    2        1
2    2020-02-05    1        3
4    2020-04-11    3        3
```

**Category**

```
Id  OriginId   DestinationId  Category
-----------------------------------------
1      1            2         Primary
2      2            1         Secondary
2      2            3         Primary
```

I want to know every `Segment` category. But not every segment exists in `Category` so some segments won't have a category.

This SQL works :

```
SELECT 
    s.*, c.name
FROM 
    Segment s
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Category c ON c.originId = s.originId AND c.destinationId = s.destinationId
```

This LINQ also works:

```
from s in Segment
join c in Category on new { s.OriginId, s.DestinationId } equals new { c.OriginId, c.DestinationId } into grouping
from c in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { s, c };
```

But to use navigation, closest I got is this: I added a property on each class respectively and setup the relationship in context using fluent api

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Segment>()
        .HasOne(segment => segment.Category)
        .WithMany(category => category.Segments)
        .HasForeignKey(segment => new { segment.OriginId, segment.DestinationId })
        .HasPrincipalKey(category => new { category.OriginId, category.DestinationId })
        .IsRequired(false);
}

// then I can do
var query = Segments.Include(o => o.Category).ToList();
```

This works to retrieve records that already exists in the database.

But to insert a new record to Segment where originId and destinationId do not exists in Category it complains about originId and destinationId not meeting the foreign key constraint. And it's ok because they don't exist in the other table.

They actually aren't foreign keys, just a column to use for joining them, but I don't khow to set this using a navigation property + Fluent Api.

Comment: EF Core (as of today) supports ONLY relationships which can be set as enforced FK relationships in database. Hence what are you asking for is not possible.

Comment: so the only way is to use Linq join instead ?

Comment: Correct (for now).

Comment: i made it work using navigation property. I dropped the fk constraint in the database and now i can insert and retrieve using Segments.Include(o => o.Category).ToList();. Its a bit hacky but its a way :D

Comment: @RobinsonHernandez you addressed a real-world problem. Nice and thanks for sharing. I have this exact scenario and have seen it at many organizations.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry - a bit late to this party.

I just went through a similar excercise. You could try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasMany(category => category.Segments)
    .WithOne(segment => segment.Category)
    .HasPrincipalKey(category => new { category.OriginId, category.DestinationId })
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Answer (score 5):

First:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "EF1001:Internal EF Core API usage.", Justification = "<挂起>")]
    public class MigrationsModelDifferWithoutForeignKey : MigrationsModelDiffer
    {
        public MigrationsModelDifferWithoutForeignKey
            ([NotNull] IRelationalTypeMappingSource typeMappingSource,
            [NotNull] IMigrationsAnnotationProvider migrationsAnnotations,
            [NotNull] IChangeDetector changeDetector,
            [NotNull] IUpdateAdapterFactory updateAdapterFactory,
            [NotNull] CommandBatchPreparerDependencies commandBatchPreparerDependencies)
            : base(typeMappingSource, migrationsAnnotations, changeDetector, updateAdapterFactory, commandBatchPreparerDependencies)
        {
        }

        public override IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
        {
            var operations = base.GetDifferences(source, target)
                .Where(op => !(op is AddForeignKeyOperation))
                .Where(op => !(op is DropForeignKeyOperation))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var operation in operations.OfType<CreateTableOperation>())
                operation.ForeignKeys?.Clear();

            return operations;
        }
    }
```

How to use:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Default);
    options.ReplaceService<IMigrationsModelDiffer, MigrationsModelDifferWithoutForeignKey>();
});
```